# How to iterate through folder with jsons and convert all of them in one single csv

Tags: python, json, pandas

Now I get only the result of last json file info. What did I miss here?

My example:

```
import os
import json
import pandas as pd


path_to_folder = 'Folder'
f1_files = os.listdir(path_to_folder)

for f in f1_files:
    if f.endswith('.json'):
        with open('%s/%s' % (path_to_folder, f), 'r') as fo:
            data = json.load(fo)
        df = pd.DataFrame(data["auto"])
        df.to_csv('data.txt')
```

Comment: you're over writing the dataframe in each part of the loop. also pandas has a `pd.read_json` method you can use to handle the IO operation you need to append each item to a container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it using `pathlib` and `pandas`

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

path_to_folder = Path('folder')

dfs = pd.concat([pd.read_json(f).assign(name=f.stem) 
                              for f in path_to_folder.glob('*.json')])
```

the list comprehension is roughly equivalent too

```
dfs = []  # <-- step you were missing
for file in path_to_folder.glob('*.json'):
    df = pd.read_json(file)
    dfs.append(df) # <-- appends each dataframe to the list.

final = pd.concat(dfs) # combines into a single dataframe.
```

Comment: @alexuuu you're very welcome, don't forget to accept this answer if it answered your query. I'd test out the different parts of the `read_json` method as you may want to select a specific node.

Comment: [see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for guidance on how to accept the question (its the green tick under the vote down arrow)

Comment: done! One more question how can I get names from json files also and add them into csv?

Comment: @alexuuu one of the benefits of using `pathlib` is that you return a posix object that gives you access to all sorts of methods and attributes. see update